# Instantiating Objects in Java

Tags: java

I asked a similar question to this recently, but I did a bad job at explaining it, so I am going to try again.

I cannot figure this out for the life of me. I have to do two different java files for this programming assignment, and when running the program from command prompt I get an error that says it cannot find symbol of when I create my object in the second class, and when I run the code in Eclipse I get the error "Error occurred during initialization of boot layer

java.lang.LayerInstantiationException: Package jdk.internal.jrtfs in both module jrt.fs and module java.base".

I even copied an example straight from the textbook to understand it, but it isn't working even though I have exactly what's in the textbook. The pastebin links are for the two classes that come from the textbook examples.

Please someone tell me what's wrong here.

First class: https://pastebin.com/KYHtDHPt

```
public class Account {
private String name;

public Account(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
}
```

Second class: https://pastebin.com/ADUsjjaR

```
public class AccountTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Account account1 = new Account("Brandon Williams");

    System.out.printf("Account one is: %s%n",account1.getName());
}
}
```

Comment: It looks like `Account` does not belong to a `package`, but maybe unrelated.  What IDE are you using? How did you create your project? Also what JDK are you using?

Comment: Eclipse, I created the project from opening Eclipse and clicking the create new project button, and I am using JDK 13.0.1

Comment: Maybe Eclipse does not support JDK 13 yet?

Comment: Possibly I suppose, or at least some features in JDK 13, because I just tried running this through command prompt and it is working now, weird.

Comment: Check your version of Eclipse. JDK 13 is supported from Eclipse 4.14 onward (rel. Dec 2019). It's quite possible that you're still on Eclipse from Fall 2019 or earlier.

Comment: You may need to let the main file know about the other file. At the top of AccountTest, you need an import statement: import Account;